# ordered list generated by php doesn't work

Tags: php, html, list, html-lists

```
<ol>
    <?php foreach ($articles as $article) { //start of the loop
        ?> //interruption to allow html to be passed rather than echoed
           <h3><li>
           <a href="article.php?id=<?php echo $article['article_id']; ?>"><?php echo $article['article_title']; ?></a>
           <small> &nbsp; postat la     
               <?php 
                   echo date('d.m.Y', $article['article_timestamp']);
               ?>
           </small>
          </li></h3>
         <?php //'starting' php again to close the loop
    } ?> //closing loop and coming back to html to allow closing the </ol>
</ol>
```

But I still don't know why i don't get the element from the database ordered.

What I get looks like:

"1." Lorem Ipsum    postat la 28.02.2013

"1." Some text    postat la 28.02.2013 (i've put quotes around them because stackoverflow it seems to autoincrement it by default)

instead of

1. Lorem Ipsum    postat la 28.02.2013
2. Some text    postat la 28.02.2013

Although Chrome displays it as it should (1 and 2) Opera and Internet Explorer display 1 for every entry. Thanks!

Comment: Dont wrap your `LI` with `H3` It's definitively an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take away the `H3` tags and you will be all right!

You shouldn't wrap your `LI` tags with anything other than `UL` or `OL`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in Your `<h3>` tags opened before `<li>`, the schema of listing is

```
<ol>
  <li>...</li>
</ol>
```

change in Your html to

```
...
<ol>
    <li><h3>...</h3></li>
</ol>
...
```

Answer (score -5):

Isn't it because of `<ol> tag` try `ul` instead. - use `<?php foreach ($articles as $i = >$article)` and display `<?= $i ?>`

Comment: I still need it numbered. jtheman got it. It was because of the h3 tag. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: `<ol>` = ordered list; `<ul>` = __un__ordered list... OP specifically says ordered

Comment: `<ol>` is an _o_ rdered list. `<ul>` is an _u_ nordered list. I.e. with numbers, or without (bullets).